# How to fix Insufficient access rights error?

Tags: powershell

In my current environment I have a local admin and domain account. I have created a powershell script which runs well when logged into my domain admin account.

I have now added:

```
$Credentials = Get-Credentials
Start-Process powershell.exe -argument C:\Users\Auser\Documents\User Leaver script test.ps1 -credential $Credentials -Verb RunAs
```

Therefore, the user is prompted for credentials. This works fine when I am signed into my domain account. However, I am presented with  Insufficient access rights to perform the operation when I run the same command to add a user to a group from my non-admin account. Even when prompted as per the above code to input my domain credentials.

> Select any number in the menu : 1
>
> Please enter new starter username: auser
>
> Please enter new starter job role: agroup
>
> Add-ADGroupMember : Insufficient access rights to perform the
>   operation At C:\Users\Auser\Documents\User Leaver script test.ps1:58
>   char:8
>   +        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $GroupName -Members $UserName
>   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Yes? If you run the code as a non-admin, wouldn't you expect this behavior? :)

Comment: Yes but I am running the code with my Domain admin account credentials using the Get-credentials part of my script.